# Unit Testing NodaTime Aliased DateTimeZone

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nodatime

I am working on a unit test for my extension method.

```
public static DateTimeZone GetDateTimeZone(this IDateTimeZoneProvider dateTimeZoneProvider, String timezoneId)
{
    DateTimeZone dateTimeZone;
    if ((dateTimeZone = dateTimeZoneProvider.GetZoneOrNull(timezoneId)) != null)
        return dateTimeZone;    

    // Continues to try and map from TimeZoneInfo if dateTimeZone == null
}
```

When unit testing this method, the test is failing as the alias is being returned for the DateTimeZone Id.

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetDateTimeZone_DateTimeZoneProviderHasTimezoneIdAsAlias_ReturnsDateTimeZone()
{
    var expectedTimezoneId = "America/New_York";
    var timezoneId = "US/Eastern";
    var dateTimeZone = _dateTimeZoneProvider.GetDateTimeZone(timezoneId); 

    Assert.AreEqual(expectedTimezoneId, dateTimeZone.Id);
}
```

As you can see, I am expecting what is in the Zone Id column (https://nodatime.org/TimeZones), but instead the alias "US/Eastern" is being returned.
This is especially surprising since the documentation on GetZoneOrNull (https://nodatime.org/2.4.x/api/NodaTime.IDateTimeZoneProvider.html#NodaTime_IDateTimeZoneProvider_GetZoneOrNull_System_String_)
says "Note that this may return a DateTimeZone that has a different ID to that requested, if the ID provided is an alias."

After reading, "Note also that this method is not required to return the same DateTimeZone instance for successive requests for the same ID; however, all instances returned for a given ID must compare as equal.",
I thought, maybe the aliased DateTimeZone would equate to the unaliased.

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetDateTimeZone_DateTimeZoneProviderHasTimezoneIdAsAlias_ReturnsDateTimeZone()
{
    var expectedDateTimeZone = _dateTimeZoneProvider.GetZoneOrNull("America/New_York");
    var timezoneId = "US/Eastern";
    var dateTimeZone = _dateTimeZoneProvider.GetDateTimeZone(timezoneId);

    Assert.AreEqual(expectedDateTimeZone, dateTimeZone);
}
```

But, it does not.  The code that calls the extension method doesn't really care about the Id as it is using the DateTimeZone to convert from LocalTime to Utc.

```
IDateTimeZoneProvider dateTimeZoneProvider = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb;
var dateTimeZone = dateTimeZoneProvider.GetDateTimeZone(timezoneId);

var zonedDateTime = dateTimeZone.AtLeniently(localDateTime);
return zonedDateTime.ToDateTimeUtc();
```

So, it will take whatever the current offset is at the time of localDateTime.  But, for unit testing purposes, I can't just check the offset as in the example of "America/New_York", because it is sometimes -5 and other times -4.  Asserting that it is either -5 or -4 in a unit test doesn't feel kosher.  How should I go about testing an aliased DateTimeZone?

### UPDATE

Here's the updated unit test using a specific date and time in which the offset is known.

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetDateTimeZone_DateTimeZoneProviderHasTimezoneIdAsAlias_ReturnsDateTimeZone()
{
    var expectedOffset = Offset.FromHours(-5);
    var specificDateTimeWithKnownUtcOffset = new DateTime(2020, 1, 15, 8, 29, 15, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    var instant = Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(specificDateTimeWithKnownUtcOffset);
    var timezoneId = "US/Eastern";
    var dateTimeZone = _dateTimeZoneProvider.GetDateTimeZone(timezoneId);

    Assert.AreEqual(expectedOffset, dateTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(instant));
}
```

Comment: This probably doesnt help much but typically I would fake the provider and use junk data. You don't need to test that microsofts provider returns the expected result, they test that. You just need to test that your code calls the provider and returns the result that the provider returned.

Comment: Why do you need to convert the DateTime object from UTC?  The ToString() method automatically applies the LocalTime Zone to the ToString method.  DateTime object standard is to transfer between machines in UTC.  I would just use UTC time in your code except where inputting from a string and outputting to a string.

Comment: I'm not converting DateTime to Utc, I'm converting NodaTime's LocalDateTime to a DateTime in Utc.

Comment: @jdweng: Treating everything as UTC without thinking about it any further is a dangerous practice. Being able to convert between time zones is definitely a valuable capability. See https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2019/03/27/storing-utc-is-not-a-silver-bullet/

Comment: Hmm. I'm surprised about this behaviour too (the fact that America/New_York isn't being returned). Will investigate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having looked at the code, we may want to modify the documentation a bit. The current behavior of `TzdbDateTimeZoneSource` is to return a `DateTimeZone` with the requested ID, but it uses the data associated with the canonical ID.

I'd argue that it's not actually violating the documented behaviour - that states that passing an alias *may* provide you with a zone with a canonical ID instead - but it's at best misleading.

I would probably write the tests to either not depend on either behavior, or to depend on the current behavior - which is unlikely to change in future versions. (It feels nicer to keep the ID that was passed.) I'll need to look into whether there are any cases where we'd actually want to return a zone with a canonical ID, but I *suspect* we can just tighten up the docs for 3.0.

If you wanted to write tests that *could* cope with both, you could just check that "the canonical ID of the returned ID is the same as the canonical ID of the passed ID" - but that seems overkill, to be honest.

Note that the offset being UTC-4 or UTC-5 isn't arbitrary - you could easily write a test that used a specific time zone ID and local date/time, and expect a given instant based on that.

Comment: The issue I am having is that since the unit test is testing that if the Id isn't returned from GetZoneOrNull, it will hit the code to try and map TimeZoneInfo timezone Id to a canonical Id and if it can gets it by Id index on dateTimeZoneProvider.  Since I am not actually choosing a date or time for this test, it could fail depending on when it is run.  I think my only option is to choose testing a timezone with only one possible offset.

Comment: @ScubaSteve: I'm not sure what you mean - `GetZoneOrNull` will return a non-null value for both the alias and the canonical ID, so that should be fine. Your `GetDateTimeZone` method doesn't check whether the ID in the returned `DateTimeZone` is the one that was requested, and it probably *shouldn't* check that. The method doesn't apply any date/time to it - so it would be reasonable to write two tests (or one parameterized test) that called `GetDateTimeZone` passing in both "US/Eastern" and "America/New_York", and in each case apply the returned zone to a *fixed* date/time.

Comment: @ScubaSteve: Basically, you haven't shown any code that uses "the current date and time" so there's nothing you've shown that would depend on when it's run. If that's some other code in your test, I would suggest fixing that - or asking another question with that code in and asking how to get rid of it.

Comment: I see my mistake.  In my test, I was looking at the Offset properties thinking that the value of those would change depending on when the test was run.  I didn't see GetUtcOffset which would allow me to pick the specific date and time in which I would know what the offset would be.

Comment: @ScubaSteve: Not sure which offset properties you mean - `DateTimeZone` is not intended to have any properties that depend on the current date/time. (There's only one tiny part of Noda Time that *does* depend on that (other than SystemClock), and that's when we need to guess at the system time zone because `TimeZoneInfo.Local` doesn't give us a useful ID.)

Comment: It's probably confusing because I was misunderstanding what the Offset properties provided and you actually know what they provide.  I've updated my question with an updated unit test that will allow me to test with canonical ids, aliases, and timezoneinfo ids.

Comment: @ScubaSteve: Right, that unit test looks fine to me. I'm still interested in what your test looked like before (that would have been test-time-dependent) but we've probably exhausted what Stack Overflow comments should be used for - feel free to ping me an email if you're interested in going into more detail :)

Comment: Sure, I'll send it to the one you have listed on your profile.